# Laravel, Image get from storage display correctly but console return status code 404

Tags: laravel-5.1

I'm having this problem where by image get from storage shows in page correctly but console shows status code 404 as shown in the image below[image]

I have noticed something weird..

This method works fine.

```
Route::get('/image/view','ImageController@display');

public function display(Request $request){
    $path = $request->path;
    $cacheimage = Image::cache(function($image)use($path){
        $file = Storage::disk('akl')->get($path);
        $ret = $image->make($file);

        return $ret;
    },10); // cache for 10 minutes

    return Response::make($cacheimage,200)->header('Content-Type','image/jpeg');
}

<img src="/image/view?path={{ $img1->path }}">
```

But this method hits error.

```
Route::get('/photo/{params?}','ImageController@get')->where('params','.*');

public function get(Request $request){
    $url = $request->fullUrl();

    #   remove domain name & photo string
    $path = substr($url,strlen(url().'/photo'),strlen($url));

    #works fine
    $file = Storage::disk('akl')->get($path);
    return Response::make($file,200)->header('Content-Type','image/jpeg');
}

<img src="/photo{{ $img1->path }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

even the code as simple as like this.

```
Route::get('/storage/{disk}/{params?}',function($disk,$params){
    $path = public_path('storage/') . $params;
    $file = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make($path);
    return $file->response('jpg');
})->where('params','.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Found myself a solution although its not my preferred way...

```
Route::get('/storage/{disk}/{params?}/something',function($disk,$params){
    $path = public_path('storage/') . $params;
    $file = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make($path);
    return $file->response('jpg');
})->where('params','.*');
```

so the url looks like this...
http://domain.com/storage/disk/picture.jpg/something

**If any out there have other solution pls do share to me.TQ!**

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you ever find a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too. Wasted much time on the changing and testing the laravel code.

The problem lies in the webserver configuration. In my case nginx. Check your web server configuration. After I apply following location block into my nginx config, no 404 anymore.

```
    #protected resources to be handled by laravel
    location ^~ /storage {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        add_header        Cache-Control public;
        add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
        expires           7d;
    }
```